# Parse date from string on Android Lollipop

Tags: android, string, date, kotlin, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a date string like `2021-02-20 12:24:10` and I need to parse it to `Date`. I have the solution, which works on Nougat (API 24) and higher, but I need need the solution for Lollipop (API 21). The solution for Nougat is below

```
val parser = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
val entryDate: Date = parser.parse(ticketResponse.entryDate)
```

I tried to use `DateFormat`, but I get `ParseException` when I try to parse my date

```
val entryDate: Date = DateFormat.getInstance().parse(ticketResponse.entryDate)
```

I understand it happens because my input string is not a standard representation of date, but I cannot easy change it, I get this date from server. I also didn't find way to set pattern for input date like for `SimpleDateFormat`.

I am surprised that where is no answer here in some old questions, all answers recommend to use `SimpleDateFormat`. Of course I can split date with dividers, but I would like to use not so bold approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you haven't noticed there are two `SimpleDateFormat` classes with a different package: `java.text.SimpleDateFormat;` and `android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat;`
please try to use the first one it is added in api level 1 chek this link :
https://www.datetimeformatter.com/how-to-format-date-time-in-kotlin/